# How do i create a Ticket command in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

Hello so i want to make a discord bot that can create tickets but i am not sure on how do it i am using discord.py and i was wondering if anyone can help? i have tried this.

```
@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    await create_text_channel(name, *, overwrites=None, reason=None, **options)
```

But it does not do anything and i get this error.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'create_text_channel' is not defined```
````

Answer (score 1):

There are three mistakes in the code you gave:

- [`create_text_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) is a [`discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create#discord.Guild) class method so it only works with a `Guild` instance
- The `name` variable isn't defined so you'd have an error.
- If you don't need any overwrites or any reason, you don't need to write `overwrites=None` and `reason=None`, same goes for `*`.

In the end, your code would look like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel('Channel Name')
```

I guess you looked at the documentation and copy pasted the method's title, which is unnecessary, you could have looked at the examples given, eg. `channel = await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')`

If you want to create a hidden channel, there's also this example:

```py
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}

channel = await guild.create_text_channel('secret', overwrites=overwrites)
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the asnwer but i would like it so when there is a channel already named ticket it creates a channel called ticket1 then 2 then 3 etc

Comment: Do you have every ticket channel under one specific category?

Comment: It would be easier, I'll edit my post in a moment :)